# set names with magrittr where both name and value are variable of data.frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, magrittr

Lets say i have the following data:

```
> data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b"))
  value name
1     1    a
2     2    b
```

**Goal:**

Can i give it as Input to the pipe Operator and "send" it to setNames (or magrittr::set_names)?

**What i have tried:**

```
library(magrittr)
data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b")) %>% 
   setNames(object = .$value, nm = .$name)
```

That doesnt work i guess, because the pipe wants to Hand over the whole data.frame and use it as a first Argument. That got me interested if i can skip this behaviour and use two subsets instead.

(So that `data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b")) %>%` is fixed and not replaced by a variable).

**Desired Output:**

How it would look like without the pipe Operator:

```
> a <- data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b"))
> setNames(object = a$value, nm = a$name)
a b 
1 2
```

Answer (score 2):

For this case, we can simply wrap it inside `{}`

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b")) %>% 
    { setNames(object = .$value, nm = .$name)}
```

---

With `tidyverse`, there is also a `deframe` which will give a `named` `vector`

```
library(tibble)
data.frame(value = 1:2, name = c("a", "b")) %>%
    select(2:1) %>%
    deframe
 #a b 
 #1 2
```

Comment: thanks a lot (and damnit). I saw that already and forgot About it. I can accept the answer in 11min. Will do it later then!